# Multiple SELECT statement in MySql , to return date_sub()

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, difference

So , this is my problem

```
SELECT comment.time,
       comment.name,
       comment.body,
       comment.contentid,
       comment.id 
FROM comment 
   WHERE comment.contentid = '$row->id' 
   ORDER BY comment.id DESC $limit
```

How is this query supposed to look , so the returned value of `comment.time` is in difference from the momment it was entered by `NOW()` and RIGHT NOW .
Table column is `datetime`

Comment: have you tried `TIMEDIFF` ?

Comment: No, i was using    date_sub , but it is allways returning mysql syntax error , i guess i am making a mistake in writing nested query.

Comment: You want the difference in days, hours, minutes, seconds?  The column `comment.time` is a datetime?

Comment: DATE_SUB can't operate in two DATETIME types, you only can substract an exact interval (or at most a TIME type)...
now try with DATEDIFF( which return days of difference) or TIMEDIFF(which should return time of difference)

Comment: Thanks for the function , but how do i write query within this query to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the exect solution to my problem is this, in case anybody needs it in future.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, comment.time, NOW()) AS hours_ago
```

This is going to return INT with value of hours from the moment comment is posted to database and RIGHT NOW.